# why Parallel.ForEach is twice slow compared with sequential loop

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Why the following `indexed parallel.foreach` is almost twice slow compared with a normal sequential loop ? Is it related to resource contention?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).Select(v => v+v);
    Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    //int index = 0;

    //foreach (double value in values)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("{0}:\t{1}", index, value);
    //    index++;
    //}
    Parallel.ForEach(values, (value, pls, index) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:\t{1}", index, value);
        index++;
    });
    Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: One does things one after another on the same thread, the other has to assign the operations to different threads, so you have to deal with the overhead.

Comment: You need to have enough work done in each thread to overcome the overhead of creating and managing the threading processes.  Simply adding/displaying a number will certainly be slower threaded.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Console` can only actually perform one `Write` at a time, so your second version is spending a lot of time creating multiple threads, scheduling work for each of them, and then just having all but one of them sitting around waiting on the others until they're all done.  You get all of the overhead of multithreading and none of the benefits, as you're not *actually* doing any work in parallel.